# integration by parts as Thomas calculus!

Tags: tikz-pgf, integral

I to do exactly the same as in the pic
I tried different ways but none gave me this result
[image]

Comment: Can you post one (or more) of the ways that you tried? Even if it doesn't work, just seeing your effort inspires others to want to help you.

Comment: Did you look into `tikzmark`s? Please rovide a [minimal working example (MWE)](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/228) so we can easier see where your problem is.

Comment: What's the purpose of the exclamation mark in the title of your posting?

Answer (score 6):

Here is an option with `nicematrix` (and `tikz`).

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{nicematrix, tikz}

\begin{document}

\NiceMatrixOptions{cell-space-limits=2mm}
\begin{NiceTabular}{c!{\qquad}c}[rules/color=cyan]\hline
\Block[l]{1-1}{\bfseries$\boldsymbol{e^{2x}}$ and its\\\bfseries derivatives} & \Block[l]{1-1}{\bfseries$\boldsymbol{\cos x}$ and its\\\bfseries integrals}\\ \hline
$\phantom{0}e^{2x}$ & $\phantom{-}\cos x$\\
$2e^{2x}$ & $\phantom{-}\sin x$\\
$4e^{2x}$ & $-\cos x$
\CodeAfter
  \tikz{
    \draw[-latex] (2-1)--node[above=-1pt]{$\scriptstyle(+)$}(3-2);
    \draw[-latex] (3-1)--node[above=-1pt]{$\scriptstyle(-)$}(4-2);
    \draw[-latex, shorten <=5mm, shorten >=5mm] (4-1)--node[above=-2pt]{$\scriptstyle(+)$}(4-2);
  }
\end{NiceTabular}

\end{document}
```